# how to have all textboxes with class have a datepicker in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I have fields that I have wrapped in div tags in order to have them specified to have a datepicker.

They look like this:

```
<div class="need-date" >
<label>Birth Date</label>
    <input id="id_birth_date" type="text"></input>
</div>
```

I know I can apply a date picker to this individual field with this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#id_birth_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
        changeYear: 'true',
        changeMonth: 'true',
        startDate: '08-24-2014',
        firstDay: 1,
        onSelect: function()
        { 

            var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); 

        }
    });

});
</script>
```

How do I apply this code to have a datepicker associate with text box wrapped in this div?

Comment: Anyway `id` should be unique, so I think ` $('#id_birth_date')` should work other wise you can say like ` $('.need-date #id_birth_date')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this way:

```
 $('.need-date #id_birth_date').datepicker({
```

or if you don't want to use id then:

```
 $('.need-date input:text').datepicker({
```